# iphone refresh images UIImageView

Tags: iphone, uiimageview

I have a rather basic question.   I have several(5) `UIImageView` images on
my screen.  When I click a button,   I want to change each image
to something else.  I also want to play a sound as each image is changed.

So I basically want a clicking sound as each image changes.

The problem is,  for some reason if I have say 5 images,
the sound gets played 5 times first and then the images change.

It's like the images only refresh when control goes back to the 
user for input.

How can I "force" it to  refresh the images as soon as i tell it what image to display?

I'm new to the iphone/macworld,  so go easy on me :-)

Rick

Comment: Any example code from handler or explanation how you connect button to response (change image/play sound). Might be just basic logical problem.

Comment: I ran through the debugger, so i know it is hitting the code correctly.  I think the response below answers the question.
If the UI is only refreshed on the main thread, then I con't do it this way.  Unless someone has any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It's like the images only refresh when control goes back to the user for input.

That's exactly what happens. The UI is updated on the main thread so no updates happen whilst your code is running.

In order to achieve what you want, you're going to need timers. Take a look at the NSTimer documentation. You need to create a timer that fires a method to change your second image and then requeue a timer to change your third image. There is a convenient method to create a timer like you need: `+ (NSTimer *)timerWithTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)seconds target:(id)target selector:(SEL)aSelector userInfo:(id)userInfo repeats:(BOOL)repeats`

```
[NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:1.0f target:self selector:@selector(updateImage2:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

then, you have a method:

```
- (void) updateImage2(NSTimer*)theTimer
{

     //Update image 2 here
     // play sound 2 here

    [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:1.0f target:self selector:@selector(updateImage3:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}
```

I'll leave it to you to implement the method updateImage3: ;-)

Running the updates like this gives the main thread a chance to update the UI.

Comment: So, how would someone accomplish this? (Seeing images display one after the other instead of all at once at the end) Would you have to drop into openGL?  Seems like such a simple thing :-)

Comment: Note that like Ben's answer in the duplicate, you can also use  -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:]

Comment: Roger,  thanks a million!  Your right I probably should have posted that sample here.  I just wasn't sure if i should have made it a comment or answer my own question so I just started fresh :-)  I really appreciate the help. I've been stuck on this for a day and a half!  I come from a Windows/Delphi background and thought I could port one of my games to iphone.  I had no delusions it would be easy, but it is proving much tougher than I thought it would be.

Thanks again for you help!

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a way to refresh the UIImageView periodically, you can reference the following: 
http://www.shanison.com/2010/12/25/uiimageview-load-remote-image/

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're probably loading the images off disk or network while playing a sound asynchronously. Perhaps you're using `AudioServicesPlaySystemSound` along with `UIImage +imageWithContentsOfURL:`? The actual image loading and sound playing code would be most useful here.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, when I wanted to change uiimageview background and refresh it, and continue executing code after that:

```
-(void)imgTapped_event:(UIImageView*)imgViewTapped
{
     imgViewTapped.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];

     //let the system update ui changes
     [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop]runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0.0f]];

     //continue your code execution, play sounds etc...

     //my helper method to play sound
     [self playSound:@"goodAnswer" sync:YES loops:0]; 
 }
```