# How can I refresh UIImagesViews differently?

Tags: iphone, graphics, uiimageview

I'm hoping someone can steer me in the right direction.

I need to be able to update images on the screen one at a time
after a button is pressed.  It appears that they only get updated 
at the end of the cycle which is not how I need it to work.

I created a little example to show what I am doing.
Basically I have 3 images on the screen.  When the button is pressed
I want to update the first image,  play a sound, wait a second and 
the update the next etc.

However,  I just hear 1 sound and all the images update at the end.

Seems like a simple thing.  How should I be doing it?

```
#import "testappViewController.h"

@implementation testappViewController


@synthesize p1,p2,p3;   //UIImageViews
@synthesize button1;
@synthesize volleyFileID;

- (IBAction)buttonpressed:(id)sender
{
    NSString *TLS = @"RQP.png";

    NSString *volleyPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"click" ofType:@"caf"];
    CFURLRef volleyURL = (CFURLRef ) [NSURL fileURLWithPath:volleyPath];
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID (volleyURL, &volleyFileID);

    TLS = @"RQP.png"; 
    UIImage *sampleimage=   [[UIImage imageNamed:TLS] retain];
    p1.image = sampleimage; 
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(volleyFileID);

    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.5];

    p2.image = sampleimage; 
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(volleyFileID);

    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.5];

    p2.image = sampleimage; 
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(volleyFileID);

}
```

Comment: You might want to reformat that with the <pre> tags, also can you include the @interface from testappViewController.h

Comment: Rick, why not post this code to your own exact duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006866/iphone-refresh-images-uiimageview

Comment: Answer posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006866/iphone-refresh-images-uiimageview/1007270#1007270

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be using -[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:] here. Try using -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:], and your latter two image changes into a separate method. Then your event loop will run as normal, your sounds will play, and your entire app will remain responsive while it's going on.